# Beginners question about VertexBuffers

Tags: xna, vertex-buffer

I'm looking at XNA for the first time in my life, and I am puzzled by the examples I read. They  contain a  duplication I don't understand:

```
        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            _verts1 = new VertexPositionTexture[6];
            _vertexBuffer1 = new VertexBuffer(
                GraphicsDevice,
                typeof(VertexPositionTexture),
                _verts1.Length,
                BufferUsage.None);
            _vertexBuffer1.SetData(_verts1);
        ...
        }

       protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
       {
        ...
            GraphicsDevice.SetVertexBuffer(_vertexBuffer1);
            foreach (EffectPass pass in effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
            {
                pass.Apply();
                GraphicsDevice.DrawUserPrimitives<VertexPositionTexture>(
                    PrimitiveType.TriangleStrip,
                    _verts1,
                    0,
                    4);
            }
         ...
        }
```

I don't understand why BOTH a VertexBuffer and a VertexPositionTexture are used in the drawing method. Sholdn't it be enough to keep the VertexBuffer around?

If I remove the calls to GraphicsDevice.SetVertexBuffer and just relies on GraphicsDevice.DrawUserPrimitives - everything looks just the same! So: what's the point of having a VertexBuffer at all when I can get along just using a VertexPositionTexture[]? :-)

(I'm sure the IS a point - plaese help me see it!!! :)

**Problem solved: crappy XNA book!** Thanks @dowhilefor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all your array containing vertices can only be rendered with DrawUserPrimitives, which is much slower because you could change your array every frame thus your vertices are pushed to the graphic card every time. A Vertexbuffer is to create a storage for your vertices and put them on the graphic card once. This of course makes the data static but also it is much faster. In fact, i guess DrawUserPrimitives creates a VertexBuffer for your vertex data on its own.

So you are mixing two different things. You created a vertex buffer, set it but then rendered your array. Have a look at [DrawPrimitives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.graphicsdevice.drawprimitives.aspx).

Comment: OK, so far so good. But how *should* the VertexBuffer be rendered then?

Comment: Not sure if you saw my edit yet. DrawPrimitives is the way to go. A Graphics card is a state mashine which means: SetVertexBuffer sets it and DrawPrimitives draws it. Unless you don't set another VertexBuffer this is the one used every time you call DrawPrimitives. This is the same for almost everything related to 3D graphics programming. Textures for example, a common mistake. Always keep track of what is set and check this first when looking for errors. Just a small advice for performance, always keep these "switches"; setting a vertex buffer, shader or texture to a minimum by sorting first.

Answer (score 1):

VertexPositionTexture vertex are stored in main memory, 
and the vertexbuffer store the vertex at gpu (graphics) memory.

When you have to draw a lot of vertex is more efficient to store them at gpu memory.

Comment: But why then use DrawUserPrimitives at all? Is the XNA book I'm reading crap?

Comment: @danbystrom If they really mix VertexBuffer and then using DrawUserPrimitves for the exact same data without explanation, than yes.